# Rails, number to currency locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use `number_to_currency`.

However, I do not know how to pass the locale if it is a variable.

In other words, `number_to_currency(100, locale: :us)` works, but `number_to_currency(100, locale: @locale)` where `@locale = "us"`, does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"us"` is a string, you need to pass in a symbol

use `@locale.to_sym`